# Add asterisk on required field with pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I would like to put an asterisk automatically with CSS for the required fields.

My markup -

```
<label for="DsrCode">DSR Code</label>
<input id="DsrCode" name="DsrCode" required="required" type="text" value="" />
```

Currently I tried -

```
input:required label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: It won't work because a `label` can never be a child of an `input` element. In-fact the `input` tag cannot have any child elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the markup can be adjusted `input` first, `label` second, it can be done with sibling selectors either using `+` or `~`.

```css
input:required + label:after {
  content: " * ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
<label>Label</label>
```

If you do need to visually display `label` first, `input` second, you can use flexbox to shift them.

```css
.fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
input:required + label:before {
  content: " * ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <input type="text" required>
  <label>Label</label>
</div>
```